# How can I get the output of delayed_job in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a "Status" page. On which I am displaying the status of my local machines such as current upload/download speed, is recording going or not.

For getting above information I am ssh into that machine. Here is my sample code for it

```
Net::SSH.start('localhost','ubuntu', :password => 'ubuntu') do |session|
    upload_speed = session.exec!("speedtest | grep Upload:").chomp.strip
    return upload_speed
end
```

But it is taking time (about 3-4 minutes) for fetching those status. And it returns me "Connection time out error". So I am trying to add this process in the background. For this I am using `delayed_job gem`

Here is my code for it
**My controller method**

```
def unit_additional_status
    @machine = MachineInfo.find(params[:unit_id])    
    stat = Delayed::Job.enqueue(LongerTask.new(@machine), 3, :run_at => 1.seconds.from_now)
end
```

Here is my longer_task.rb file

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'net/ssh'

    class LongerTask < Struct.new(:machine)
      def perform
             port = @machine.port
             @status = Hash.new
             Net::SSH.start('localhost','ubuntu', :password => 'ubuntu', :port => port) do |session|
              upload_speed = session.exec!("speedtest | grep Upload:").chomp.strip
              status["upload_speed"].push(upload_speed) 
            end
            @status
      end
end
```

After execution I have to pass this  `@status` to my controller action so that I can pass it to my `status.html.erb` view.

So I have a question how can I pass it to my controller method or how can get the output of execution of delayed job.

Also, if any one have better solution then let me know.

I am using `rails 3.2.14` and `ruby 1.8.7`

Comment: The whole point of delayed jobs is that they are running in background and you don't know when they'll be run. They can be scheduled today and run tomorrow. Getting any data from them makes no sense, as the user would need to wait random amount of time to get this data.

Comment: @BroiSatse, So for this `delayed_job` is not a good solution.

Comment: is there any other way for doing it?

Comment: If the result is important here but takes quite a lot of time to be calculated, I think the best option is to firstly display 'Please wait until we calculate the results, it might take a while' page, which automatically send an AJAX request to your server which then calculates the data and redirects customer to the result page. Nothing is worse for the user than waiting 10 minutes without any warning.

Comment: @BroiSatse, thanks for your suggestion, but I have doubt if I implement same functionality is it affect on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some kind of additional status model, e.g. `Job (status:string, message:string)`. Then you pass an instance of this model to your delayed job task when it is scheduled. When the task starts executing, you set the status to 'running'. When it finishes you update the message field with the desired result information and set status to 'finished'. This has several benefits like you have a good overview of your job queue and it can be extended to reflect execution time, errors etc.

To display the machine status in your example, you simply select the latest Job with status='finished' and show its timestamp and message.